# The remote server returned an error

Tags: c#, json, httpwebresponse, server-error

I am trying to read a JSON stream of data like so-

```
string Username = "username";
string Password = "password";

string BaseUrl = "url";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BaseUrl);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) throw new Exception(string.Format("Server returned {0}\n {1}", response.StatusCode, response.ToString()));
    // Cheat and always expect utf-8
    string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();

    richTextBox1.Text = result;
```

I'm not sure if this is the basic way to gain authentication by passing in the username and password in as strings however one execution I get the following error-

> The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.

How can I get past this?

Comment: Maybe stupid question  do you have access to the server ?

Comment: Are you sure the given login has access?

Comment: Please don't add " C#" to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Also, if this login is an AD login, for example, how are you handling domains?

Comment: The credentials supplied are the login details that gains access to the servers, however this may not be the right way to pass them in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a header authentication instead of doing by NetworkCreddentials

```
public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest req, String userName, String userPassword)
{
  string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
  authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
  req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
}
```

Comment: Right I have added that code and it now returns - The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.

Comment: Put the right accept content type of your stream. req.Accept="audio/mpeg"; for example

Comment: right ill give that a bash, will mark as correct if it works.

Comment: its a json stream that im trying to consume?

Comment: so try re.accept = "application/json" i'm just getting confuse when you said stream from a json call, nut it is ok